# use route reference to edit nested dictionary in python

Tags: python

From : http://connor-johnson.com/2015/02/28/generate-a-tree-structure-in-python/

with :

```
places=[['US', 'Central', 'Louisiana', 'Monroe'], ['US', 'Central', 'Texas', 'Midland'], ['US', 'Pacific', 'California', 'East Palo Alto']]
```

I can build :

```
placesDict={'US': {'Central': {'Louisiana': {'Monroe': {}}, 'Texas': {'Midland': {}}}, 'Pacific': {'California': {'East Palo Alto': {}}}}}
```

now I have a list , `placesCode=['318','432','650 ']`

How to use 'places' and 'placesCode' as reference to retouch placesDict to :

```
placesDict={'US': {'Central': {'Louisiana': {'Monroe': '318'}, 'Texas': {'Midland': '432'}}, 'Pacific': {'California': {'East Palo Alto': '650'}}}}
```

Sincerely
-bino-

Comment: This is going to be a bit difficult, as dictionaries in Python are not ordered. If your list of place codes corresponds to the order in the places list, there's no guarantee (and it's unlikely) that placesDict will be in the same order. You could, I suppose, use an ordered dict. The solution to your problem, however, is going to depend on the structure you're trying to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use nested for loops to loop through and initialize a variable to keep a track of which code you need:

```
>>> cur = 0
>>> placesCode=['318','432','650 ']
>>> for i in placesDict.values()[0].values():
...     for j in i.values():
...             j[j.keys()[0]] = placesCode[cur]
...             cur+=1
... 
>>> placesDict
{'US': {'Central': {'Louisiana': {'Monroe': '318'}, 'Texas': {'Midland': '432'}}, 'Pacific': {'California': {'East Palo Alto': '650 '}}}}
>>>
```